# Semi transparent webview background in android

Tags: android, json, webview

**EDIT: My Current solution. Was wrap the json in a div tag and set it to transparent as well.**

I am populating a webview from a json object remotely.

```
{
"message": "<p style=\"color:#EEEEEE;background-color:transparent;font-family:'Arial Narrow','Nimbus Sans L',sans-serif;\"><\/p><p style=\"color:#EEEEEE;background-color:transparent;font-family:'Arial Narrow','Nimbus Sans L',sans-serif;\">The mission of the Canton Police Department is to protect the lives and properties of the citizens of Canton, enforce all city, state, and federal law<\/p>",
"nationalad": ""
}
```

I can get the webview background to be transparent. But not semi transparent.  When I try this:

```
webView1.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(128, 00, 00, 000));
```

I get a black background with a tiny vertical transparent strip on the right.  To make it transparent all the way:

```
webView1.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
```

Here is how I am bringing in the JSON:

```
  try{
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray nameArray = json.names();
                JSONArray valArray = json.toJSONArray(nameArray);
                for (int i = 0; i < valArray.length(); i++)
                {      
                    WebView webView1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
                   // webView1.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);

                    //webView1.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, valArray.getString(0), "text/html", "utf-8", null);   
                    webView1.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(128, 00, 00, 00));
                }
```

EDIT: XML

```
    <!-- Included header.xml here -->

    <ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/vsHeader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inflatedId="@+id/header"
        android:layout="@layout/header" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/cpd"
        android:gravity="center|center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp" >

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView1"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: What does your XML layout look like for this page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your setBackgroundColor call to the following:

```
    webView1.setBackgroundColor(0xAA000000);
```

This should give you a semi transparent black. The first two entries are the alpha values. The lower the value the more transparent the color will be.

Comment: hmm i get the same black background with the tiny strip.  Its like this works but then the black is laid on top of it. I'm stumped. I added a pic

Comment: Same problem here, this works on all kinds of Android views except WebView

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

on your **web** page body:

```
background-color:transparent
```

on your **java** activity:

```
webView.loadUrl("yourwebpage");
webView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000); 
webView.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

and you **must** set the hardwareAccelerated **false** for your activity:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

Comment: how to set hardwareAccelerated to false if the view is not created via a XML layout file ?

Comment: You don't really need to set hardwareAccelerated false, at least not for Android 4.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

just try this :

```
webView.setAlpha(0);  /*or for semi transparent : webView.setAlpha(0.5f);*/
```